# Whether monitor is off without appealing to X or /proc

Tags: console, monitors

How can I know whether the monitor is on or off if `X` is not running, and without appealing to `/proc/acpi/video`? The latter isn't available from my kernel.

If `X` is running it's just a matter of

```
  $ DISPLAY=:0 xset -q 2>/dev/null| grep "^\s*Monitor is"
```

But what if `X` is **not** running?

Comment: I bet there's an answer buried somewhere in `/sys`

Answer (score 1):

Looking through this Q&A on StackOverflow titled: [How to Determine if LCD Monitor is Turned on From Linux Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433203/how-to-determine-if-lcd-monitor-is-turned-on-from-linux-command-line) I found this utility called [ddccontrol](http://ddccontrol.sourceforge.net/) that says it can report if a monitor is turned on or off.  You can check out the [documentation for using version 0.4](http://ddccontrol.sourceforge.net/doc/0.4/).

You can basically run this command:

```
$ ddccontrol -p
```

If it returns any output, then the monitor is on, if it returns nothing the monitor is off.

#### References

- [ddccontrol github repository](https://github.com/ddccontrol/ddccontrol)
- [ddccontrol project page](http://redmine.ddccontrol.org/projects/ddccontrol)

Comment: The OP is doing this already. The main question is what to do if X is not running.

Comment: @JosephR. - see updates.